# How to bundle css with Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, bundle, minify

I have a simple Webpack configuration that looks through all folders under 'src/build', take the individual js files and minified and bundles them into one 'production' file located at 'dist/main.js'. Here's the Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    js: glob.sync('./lib/build/**/*.js'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

Now I want to do the same thing with 'css' files.

I came across the following blog that shows how to do it using the ExtractTextWebpackPlugin plugin but it looks like this is now deprecated.
https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09

I also looked at 'css-loader' in the Webpack docs but it doesn't seem to be a fitting solution for what I'm trying to do.

To recap, what I'm trying to achieve is have Webpack look at all the css files in this location:

```
./lib/build/**/*.css
```

and minify and bundle them all into 1 output file, which would be

```
./dist/main.css
```

Note: For context this is for a React component library. Normally I would get this behavior out of the box with create-react-app, but I'm not using it in this case, so trying to replicate it manually with Webpack.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Update: I ended up using the 'css-loader' which resolves the css import in the React component and adds the css to the 'dist/main.js' file. My original plan was to try to get a separate 'dist/main.css' file to be generated but this approach works just as well, if not better.